# Dynamically Create new columns where iin new columns as per their name LHS becomes 0 and RHS remains same

Tags: r

I have a dataset (nm) which has following columns:

```
nm

   X24_TT_1.1   X35_FTT_2.1  X55_FTT_3.1  X70_FTT_4.1  X1085_TT_5.1 Mean    Median
    0.09          0.87        0.89          0.15        0.1          35      55
    0.94          0.12        0.09          0.92        0.82         55      55
    0.89          0.11        0.86          0.08        0.08         70      35 
    0.12          0.8         0.15          0.18        0.12         35      35
    0.08          0.09        0.15          0.88        0.12         85      24
```

I want to have new dataset (df) with following conditions:

a) Whichever is highest between Mean and Median, the new columns will show LHS value as "0" and RHS should have same previous values.

b) New columns must have "_P" added at the last of their column names

c) As number of columns is very large, so dynamic coding is needed

For e.g.

In Row 1: As 55>35 then select 55 as threshold and set X55_TT as column where the columns which have names/values i.e X24_TT and X35_TT i.e. 24 and 35 are less than 55 should show "0" as value and columns greater than 55 i.e. X_70_FTT & X_1085TT will show same previous values.

Similarly for Row 3: As 70>35, It should show "0" before 70(LHS) and previous values after 70(RHS)

The new dataset(df) will show like this:

```
df

X24_TT_1.1  X35_FTT_2.1  X55_FTT_3.1  X70_FTT_4.1  X1085_TT_5.1 Mean    Median  X24_TT___1.1_P  X35_FTT_2.1_P   X55_FTT__3.1_P  X70_FTT__4.1_P  X1085_TT_5.1_P
0.09        0.87          0.89         0.15       0.1           35       55       0                0              0.89             0.15            0.1
0.94        0.12          0.09         0.92       0.82          55       55       0                0              0.09             0.92            0.82
0.89        0.11          0.86         0.08       0.08          70       35       0                0              0                0.08            0.08
0.12        0.8           0.15         0.18       0.12          35       35       0                0.8           0.15              0.18            0.12
0.08        0.09          0.15         0.88       0.12          85       24       0                0               0                 0            0.12
```

I have tried several methods but dynamic coding doesn't work for me.

Thanks in  advance for providing the solution !!

Comment: The output showed is not that clear.  Can you explain a bit more.  Why you have 0.15 for X55_FTT_P when the 'Mean' and 'Median' column does not have that index for the 4th row.  What is the LHS and RHS you mentioned in the post?

Comment: @akrun I have provided an example to illustrate the problem

Comment: @akrun  Apology as I have edited my column name since it contains two numeric value as shown above..... now kindly provide the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to extract the numeric substring from the column names with `gsub` ('j1'), loop through the rows (`apply(nm, 1, ...`), get the max value of 'Mean', and 'Median' (`i1`), assign the first 5 elements to 0 where the 'j1' is less than 'i1', subset the first 5 values, transpose the output and assign it to new columns.

```
j1 <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", names(nm)[1:5]))
nm[paste0(names(nm)[1:5], "_P")] <- t(apply(nm, 1, FUN = function(x) {
        i1 <- max(x[6:7])
        x[1:5][j1 < i1] <- 0
        x[1:5] 

     }))

nm    
# X24_TT X35_FTT X55_FTT X70_FTT X85_TT Mean Median X24_TT_P X35_FTT_P
#1   0.09    0.87    0.89    0.15   0.10   35     55        0       0.0
#2   0.94    0.12    0.09    0.92   0.82   55     55        0       0.0
#3   0.89    0.11    0.86    0.08   0.08   70     35        0       0.0
#4   0.12    0.80    0.15    0.18   0.12   35     35        0       0.8
#5   0.08    0.09    0.15    0.88   0.12   85     24        0       0.0
#  X55_FTT_P X70_FTT_P X85_TT_P
#1      0.89      0.15     0.10
#2      0.09      0.92     0.82
#3      0.00      0.08     0.08
#4      0.15      0.18     0.12
#5      0.00      0.00     0.12
```

---

Or we can vectorize using `rep`, create a logical matrix, multiply with first 5 columns of 'nm' and assign the output to the new columns

```
res <- nm[1:5]*matrix(rep(j1, nrow(nm)) >= rep(do.call(pmax, nm[6:7]), 
                            each = 5), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
nm[paste0(names(nm)[1:5], "_P")] <- res
nm
#X24_TT X35_FTT X55_FTT X70_FTT X85_TT Mean Median X24_TT_P X35_FTT_P X55_FTT_P X70_FTT_P X85_TT_P
#1   0.09    0.87    0.89    0.15   0.10   35     55        0       0.0      0.89      0.15     0.10
#2   0.94    0.12    0.09    0.92   0.82   55     55        0       0.0      0.09      0.92     0.82
#3   0.89    0.11    0.86    0.08   0.08   70     35        0       0.0      0.00      0.08     0.08
#4   0.12    0.80    0.15    0.18   0.12   35     35        0       0.8      0.15      0.18     0.12
#5   0.08    0.09    0.15    0.88   0.12   85     24        0       0.0      0.00      0.00     0.12
```

#### Update

For the new column names, change the 'j1' to

```
j1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", names(nm)[1:5]))
```

and copy pasting the above code gives

```
res <- nm[1:5]*matrix(rep(j1, nrow(nm)) >= rep(do.call(pmax, nm[6:7]), 
                            each = 5), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
nm[paste0(names(nm)[1:5], "_P")] <- res
nm
#   X24_TT_1.1 X35_FTT_2.1 X55_FTT_3.1 X70_FTT_4.1 X1085_TT_5.1 Mean Median X24_TT_1.1_P X35_FTT_2.1_P X55_FTT_3.1_P X70_FTT_4.1_P X1085_TT_5.1_P
#1       0.09        0.87        0.89        0.15         0.10   35     55            0           0.0          0.89          0.15           0.10
#2       0.94        0.12        0.09        0.92         0.82   55     55            0           0.0          0.09          0.92           0.82
#3       0.89        0.11        0.86        0.08         0.08   70     35            0           0.0          0.00          0.08           0.08
#4       0.12        0.80        0.15        0.18         0.12   35     35            0           0.8          0.15          0.18           0.12
#5       0.08        0.09        0.15        0.88         0.12   85     24            0           0.0          0.00          0.00           0.12
```

#### data

```
nm <- structure(list(X24_TT = c(0.09, 0.94, 0.89, 0.12, 0.08), X35_FTT = c(0.87, 
0.12, 0.11, 0.8, 0.09), X55_FTT = c(0.89, 0.09, 0.86, 0.15, 0.15
), X70_FTT = c(0.15, 0.92, 0.08, 0.18, 0.88), X85_TT = c(0.1, 
0.82, 0.08, 0.12, 0.12), Mean = c(35L, 55L, 70L, 35L, 85L), Median = c(55L, 
55L, 35L, 35L, 24L)), .Names = c("X24_TT", "X35_FTT", "X55_FTT", 
"X70_FTT", "X85_TT", "Mean", "Median"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```